# write external storage problem android stufio

Tags: android, kotlin

WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE not working in android 13 so how to save image in the storage from an application
android studio code

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
and checked in my android 13 device
but not working I want it to work so save my image of application in my phone

Comment: You should not request that permission at runtime for an Android 13 device to begin with. Further we have no idea what you mean by 'not working'.

Comment: The best solution is to use the Storage Access Framework, letting the user decide what and where your app uses storage on the user's phone. Or, use methods on `Context`, like `getExternalFilesDir()`. Neither of those techniques requires any permissions.

Comment: What have you tried? Where is your code?